# Efficient and fast way to extract information from multiple levels data

Tags: list-manipulation, data, associations

I have a large collection of data with multi levels. An example of the data (in `Association` shape) is [here](https://app.box.com/s/gid31sij901mnfpm2kk4h95c79zykyek).

The data looks like this:

```
data = ToExpression[Import["test"]];
data[[;; , ;; 3]]
```

[image]

I am looking for fast way to extract the data from all Keys when the time (the last column) is within certain values.

If you see the following plot, I am looking to extract the data from all Keys within 5 seconds around each peaks when the peaks are above certain values compare to certain Key (say Key "G32" when the values are more than 20).

```
    DateListPlot[data[[;; , ;; 200, {-1, 2}]], PlotRange -> All, 
 GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]

If I choose "G32" as my reference for selection then the time that I need to extract the data around is:

```
    allevents = 
  First /@ Split[
    Select[data[["G32"]], #[[2]] > 20 &], #2[[-1]] - #1[[-1]] < 5 &];
```

and this result is like this:

```
DateListPlot[data[[;; , ;; 900, {-1, 2}]], PlotRange -> All, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[0.01], Point[allevents[[;; , {-1, 2}]]]}]
```

[image]

What I am facing is the difficulty to efficiently and quickly extract the data around each time of `allevents` within 5 seconds. Currently I am using this method but it takes too long:

```
alleventstime = allevents[[;; , -1]];
AbsoluteTiming[
 eventsdata = 
   Table[Select[#, Abs[#[[-1]] - i] <= 5 &], {i, alleventstime}] & /@ 
    data;]
{252.585, Null}
```

Part of the result looks like this:
[image]

Any idea how can I do that fast. I have tried couple of other methods but no much luck.

Thank you

Comment: @Edmund, the data is provided in the link at the beginning of the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [`PeakDetect`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PeakDetect.html) to find the peaks combined with the [Date & Time](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/DateAndTime.html) and [Interval Arithmetic](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/IntervalArithmetic.html) guides to reduce the evaluation time.

The time is being extended because you are making a complete pass of each set of data for each peak window.  A method that makes only one pass for all peak windows will significantly drop the time.

With `data` as defined in the OP.

Then the location of the peaks can be obtained by

```
peakLocs = Position[1]@PeakDetect[data[["G32", All, 2]], Automatic, Automatic, 20]
```

> ```
> {{45},{56},{98},{166},{190},{195},{342},{352},{396},{465},{514},
>  <<369>>,
>  {17571},{17658},{17663},{17674},{17704},{17729},{17732},{17773},{17786},{17811},{17823}}
> ```

[`DatePlus`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DatePlus.html) can be used with [`Interval`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interval.html) to create a 5 second interval about these peaks.  [`IntervalUnion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntervalUnion.html) can then join these `Interval`s into one.

```
intervalWindows =
  Interval@
      {
       AbsoluteTime@DatePlus[DateObject@data[["G32", #, -1]], {-5, "Second"}],
       AbsoluteTime@DatePlus[DateObject@data[["G32", #, -1]], {5, "Second"}]
      } & /@
     Flatten@peakLocs // Apply[IntervalUnion];
```

> ```
> Interval[{3.69061*10^9,3.69061*10^9},{3.69061*10^9,3.69061*10^9},
>     <<372>>,
>     {3.70582*10^9,3.70582*10^9}]
> ```

[`IntervalMemberQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntervalMemberQ.html) can be used with [`Select`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html) to make one pass on each set of data that returns all items in the peak windows. This runs in less than a second.

```
selected = Select[IntervalMemberQ[intervalWindows, Last@#] &] /@ data;
```

A quick visual check indicates that all is well.

```
DateListPlot[selected[[All, ;; 50, {-1, 2}]], Joined -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.